# How can I access the ui thread in an asynchronous httpwebrequest callback in a bho

Tags: c#, multithreading, bho

I'm struggling to get access to the ui thread in an asynchronous httpwebrequest callback in a browser helper object. The current document and windows don't reflect those witnessed on the calling thread, so I can't update the UI as required.

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain what context you're in, but in WinForms, you can access the main Form's UI thread from another thread with `form.Invoke()` like this:

```
        // Assuming the following Form and method:
        Form form = ...
        Action method = ...

        // Invoke the method like this, so it is run in the UI thread.
        if (form.InvokeRequired)
        {
            form.Invoke(method);
        }
        // If we are already in the UI thread, 
        // just run the method without an invoke.
        else 
        {
            method();
        }
```